# how to grab inside text using style information with htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to grab the sold number which inside `style="vertical-align: inherit;"`. Please check i already tried to grab that but this returns null. How can i fix it? Please note i am using htmlagilitypack.

What i already tried:

```
var SoldNumber = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//font[contains(@style,'vertical-align: inherit;')]").ElementAt(0).InnerText;
```

html:

```
<div class="item-conditions"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">

                New - 14 sold

        </font></font>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I tried and got the output as desired.

```
    string text = @"
        <div class=""item - conditions""><font style=""vertical-align: inherit;""><font style=""vertical-align: inherit;"">New - 14 sold</font></font>
        </div>";

    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(text);
    var htmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//font[@style='vertical-align: inherit;']");
    Console.WriteLine(htmlNode.First().InnerText);
```

**Difference:** What I did was, removed the 'contains' in the XPath query. Simply using, `//font[@style='vertical...]` gives you an array of all the possibilities. Using any of these to get the InnerText would give you the text that you are looking for.

`// output: New - 14 sold`